# Compatibility of two atlases on $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle. It is a smooth manifold with various atlases. In Chapter 5 of Tu's, An Introduction to Manifolds, the author gives two atlases, other than that defined through stereographic projection. Using his notations, I want to study the compatibility of the previous atlases.

First Atlas: $\{(U_1^+,\Phi_1^+),(U_1^-,\Phi_1^-),(U_2^+,\Phi_2^+),(U_2^-,\Phi_2^-)\}$, where $U_1^+=\{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x>0 \}$ and $\Phi_1^+(x,y)=y$. The other maps are defined similarly, where the sign minus occurs we assume the chosen coordinate to be negative.

Second Atlas: $(U_1=S^1 \setminus \{(-1,0)\},\Phi_1)$ with $\Phi_1(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))=t$ ($\Phi_1: U_1 \to (-\pi,\pi)$) and the chart $(U_2=S^1 \setminus \{(1,0)\},\Phi_2)$ with $\Phi_2$ defined in the same way.

I think they are not compatibile. I get (hoping to be correct)

$\Phi^+_1(\Phi_2^{-1}): \Phi_2(U_2 \cap U_1^+)=(0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \cup (\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi) \to \Phi_1^+(U_2 \cap U_1^+)=(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$

$$
t \mapsto \sin(t)
$$

Why is this function not continuous (so that there is incompatibility of the charts)

Comment: The map $t\mapsto \sin(t)$ is not a map from $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})\cup(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi)\to(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your comment. Please, is it possible to analyze in detail in an answer the compatibility (or incompatibility) of the charts of the two atlases I'm referring at

Comment: I have no idea how your map is defined. What does $t\mapsto\sin(t)$ in your question? That can't be the map since sine is not defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Please give more information on your open cover and coordinate functions.

Comment: Of course the function is continuous. Why do you say it is not?

Comment: The other cases are similar. So  are these atlases compatible? This is so strange. In the meanwhile, are my computations correct?

Comment: Sure. The “overlap maps” are indeed smooth.

Comment: Just add a comment. Dimension 4 is the lowest dimension where exotic phenomena  may occur (id est, multiple non-equivalent differential structures on a given topological manifold). Therefore, you cannot find a smooth atlas on $S^1$ which is not compatible with the ones you described.

Comment: I think that the equivalence is given in terms of diffeomorphisms between manifolds. For instance $(\mathbb{R}, Id)$ and $(\mathbb{R},x^3)$. These are not compatible, but there exists a diffeomorphism between this two manifolds.